# Add column to csv with value

Tags: java

I’m setting up a new script, and want to add a column with value "No" in a csv. What do I need to set the encoding?

```
Before: | After:

Text1     Text1, No
Text2     Text2, No
Text3     Text3, No
Text4     Text4, No
```

Adding on all lines the value "No", no matter what text is in column 1.

Comment: Hey, can you rephrase the question a bit? I am having some trouble understanding what you want.

Comment: are you using java or javascript?

Comment: Adding a column with "No" in a csv: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 and above:

Read the CSV:

```
final String SEPARATOR = ";";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(PATH, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          // Add "No"      
          list.add(line + SEPARATOR + "No");
      }

} catch (IOException e) {
      throw e;
}
```

And after that:
Print the List in a .csv-file

```
try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(PATH))) {
      for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
         pw.println(liste.get(i);   
      }
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw e;       
}
```

Note: If you dont want a new cell for "no" then leave out SEPARATOR.

Note also: You can choose the Charset as you need it.